# syntaxnet ./configure error

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I was trying to using syntaxnet and I have finished most of processes. Upgrade bazel version to 0.43 in case of errors (Ubuntu 16.04 Ver, Anaconda python 2.7).
However, I am having a troubles with ./configure part. I am reading the official instruction via tensorflow github.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
cd models/syntaxnet/tensorflow
**./configure**
cd ..
bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
# On Mac, run the following:
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names \
  syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

Following logs will help you to understand what’s going on my machine.  Thanks for the advice

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /home/ryan/anaconda2/bin/python]: 
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /home/ryan
  /home/ryan/pynaoqi-python2.7
  /home/ryan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/home/ryan]
/home/ryan/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GPU support? [y/N] y
GPU support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: 
Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 8.0
Please specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system default]: 5.0
Please specify the location where cuDNN 5.0 library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
Invalid path to cuDNN  toolkit. Neither of the following two files can be found:
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libcudnn.so.5.0
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/libcudnn.so.5.0
.5.0
Please specify the Cudnn version you want to use. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where cuDNN  library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: 
libcudnn.so resolves to libcudnn.5
Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size.
[Default is: "3.5,5.2"]: 
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=120
INFO: Reading options for 'clean' from /home/ryan/git_ryan/models/syntaxnet/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --force_python=py2 --host_force_python=py2 --python2_path=/home/ryan/anaconda2/bin/python --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/home/ryan/anaconda2/bin/python --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone
**INFO: Reading options for 'clean' from /etc/bazel.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --action_env=PATH --action_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH --action_env=TMPDIR --test_env=PATH --test_env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Unrecognized option: --action_env=PATH
ERROR: /home/ryan/git_ryan/models/syntaxnet/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:568:26: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/ryan/git_ryan/models/syntaxnet/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl", line 562
        rule(attrs = {"srcs": attr.label_list..."), <3 more arguments>)}, <2 more arguments>)
    File "/home/ryan/git_ryan/models/syntaxnet/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl", line 568, in rule
        attr.label_list(cfg = "data", allow_files = True)
expected ConfigurationTransition or NoneType for 'cfg' while calling label_list but got string instead: data.
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package '': Extension file 'tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl' has errors.
Configuration finished**
```

Comment: I found some old [github issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4319) around this. You probably saw them already. Most of the users fixed this by upgrading bazel which you mention you have done already. Just for sanity could you post the output of "bazel version" or "which bazel" here. If the version is fine it would be great if you could file a [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) issue for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the version of your bazel is too high for Syntaxnet. you can try bazel-0.3.1 please.